# How can I use my new Miles & More membership?

Tags: air-india, miles-and-more

After being extremely confused on how Miles & More and Star Alliance and the other big alliances (SkyTeam and Oneworld) work, I decided to register at the Miles & More website.

From what I'm able to understand, I can give the new card number to a member airline and they will simply add the miles to my card. After a set number of miles, they will be able to send the card to my address.

My next flight is with Air India which is to be added into Star Alliance in June. My flight is in August, after which I plan to take two more flights with Lufthansa which are also in August.

Now, in order to get my miles and the permanent card, what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to present your M&M account number at the check-in or apply for retroactive credit for a flight online at miles-and-more.com under the menu point "Mileage request".

---

There is no real harm in registering at all the frequent flier programs where you are able to earn miles on. The airline has your data anyhow already once you take a flight, so there is no privacy issue (as long as you do not use the card/number otherwise), and you do not pay any fees. Many programs also apply to car rentals, hotel bookings etc, so you can earn miles in several places.

To get the miles on your card, normally all you need to do is to present your card/number at check-in and you will get the points. Once you have a certain minimum amount of points, you will get the physical card. If you do not have a card yet, or forgot it, you can simply give them the number or apply retroactively on-line. You can also take a photo of your card and store it on your smartphone so there is no issue in case you do not carry them with you.

Comment: Is there something I can do about my Old Miles as well?? More like I've taken more Lufthansa flights in the past. Is there any chance I can get the miles for them? No right?

Comment: There is a deadline and you need to have the boarding pass. check on the Miles and more website for details.